# Meteor: "=> Exited with code: 8" error

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteorite, meteor-blaze, meteor-helper

Just getting started with Meteor, following the tutorial presented in *[Discover Meteor](https://www.discovermeteor.com/)*.

After implementing code from Chapter 3, I kept getting the following error:

```
W20150714-18:47:36.539(-7)? (STDERR)          
W20150714-18:47:36.540(-7)? (STDERR) /Users/TXC/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1wysac9++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:245
W20150714-18:47:36.540(-7)? (STDERR)                        throw(ex);
W20150714-18:47:36.540(-7)? (STDERR)                              ^
W20150714-18:47:36.541(-7)? (STDERR) TypeError: undefined is not a function
W20150714-18:47:36.541(-7)? (STDERR)     at app/collections/posts.js:1:44
W20150714-18:47:36.541(-7)? (STDERR)     at app/collections/posts.js:3:3
W20150714-18:47:36.541(-7)? (STDERR)     at /Users/TXC/code/microscope/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:222:10
W20150714-18:47:36.541(-7)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
W20150714-18:47:36.541(-7)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (/Users/TXC/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1wysac9++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
W20150714-18:47:36.541(-7)? (STDERR)     at /Users/TXC/code/microscope/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:117:5
=> Exited with code: 8
W20150714-18:47:38.256(-7)? (STDERR)          
W20150714-18:47:38.256(-7)? (STDERR) /Users/TXC/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1wysac9++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:245
W20150714-18:47:38.257(-7)? (STDERR)                        throw(ex);
W20150714-18:47:38.257(-7)? (STDERR)                              ^
W20150714-18:47:38.259(-7)? (STDERR) TypeError: undefined is not a function
W20150714-18:47:38.259(-7)? (STDERR)     at app/collections/posts.js:1:44
W20150714-18:47:38.259(-7)? (STDERR)     at app/collections/posts.js:3:3
W20150714-18:47:38.259(-7)? (STDERR)     at /Users/TXC/code/microscope/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:222:10
W20150714-18:47:38.259(-7)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
W20150714-18:47:38.259(-7)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (/Users/TXC/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1wysac9++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
W20150714-18:47:38.259(-7)? (STDERR)     at /Users/TXC/code/microscope/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:117:5
=> Exited with code: 8
W20150714-18:47:39.821(-7)? (STDERR)          
W20150714-18:47:39.822(-7)? (STDERR) /Users/TXC/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1wysac9++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:245
W20150714-18:47:39.822(-7)? (STDERR)                        throw(ex);
W20150714-18:47:39.822(-7)? (STDERR)                              ^
W20150714-18:47:39.824(-7)? (STDERR) TypeError: undefined is not a function
W20150714-18:47:39.825(-7)? (STDERR)     at app/collections/posts.js:1:44
W20150714-18:47:39.825(-7)? (STDERR)     at app/collections/posts.js:3:3
W20150714-18:47:39.825(-7)? (STDERR)     at /Users/TXC/code/microscope/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:222:10
W20150714-18:47:39.825(-7)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
W20150714-18:47:39.825(-7)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (/Users/TXC/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1wysac9++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
W20150714-18:47:39.825(-7)? (STDERR)     at /Users/TXC/code/microscope/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:117:5
=> Exited with code: 8
=> Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change.
=> Modified -- restarting.
W20150714-18:53:37.467(-7)? (STDERR)          
W20150714-18:53:37.468(-7)? (STDERR) /Users/TXC/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1wysac9++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:245
W20150714-18:53:37.468(-7)? (STDERR)                        throw(ex);
W20150714-18:53:37.468(-7)? (STDERR)                              ^
W20150714-18:53:37.470(-7)? (STDERR) TypeError: undefined is not a function
W20150714-18:53:37.471(-7)? (STDERR)     at app/collections/posts.js:1:44
W20150714-18:53:37.471(-7)? (STDERR)     at app/collections/posts.js:3:3
W20150714-18:53:37.471(-7)? (STDERR)     at /Users/TXC/code/microscope/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:222:10
W20150714-18:53:37.471(-7)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
W20150714-18:53:37.471(-7)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (/Users/TXC/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1wysac9++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
W20150714-18:53:37.471(-7)? (STDERR)     at /Users/TXC/code/microscope/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:117:5
=> Exited with code: 8
=> Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change.
=> Modified -- restarting.
=> Errors prevented startup:                  

   While building the application:
   client/views/posts/post_item.js:9:2: Unexpected token )

=> Your application has errors. Waiting for file change.
=> Modified -- restarting.                    
W20150714-18:56:52.185(-7)? (STDERR)          
W20150714-18:56:52.185(-7)? (STDERR) /Users/TXC/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1wysac9++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:245
W20150714-18:56:52.186(-7)? (STDERR)                        throw(ex);
W20150714-18:56:52.186(-7)? (STDERR)                              ^
W20150714-18:56:52.188(-7)? (STDERR) TypeError: undefined is not a function
W20150714-18:56:52.188(-7)? (STDERR)     at app/collections/posts.js:1:44
W20150714-18:56:52.188(-7)? (STDERR)     at app/collections/posts.js:3:3
W20150714-18:56:52.188(-7)? (STDERR)     at /Users/TXC/code/microscope/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:222:10
W20150714-18:56:52.188(-7)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
W20150714-18:56:52.189(-7)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (/Users/TXC/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1wysac9++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
W20150714-18:56:52.189(-7)? (STDERR)     at /Users/TXC/code/microscope/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:117:5
=> Exited with code: 8
W20150714-18:56:53.775(-7)? (STDERR)          
W20150714-18:56:53.775(-7)? (STDERR) /Users/TXC/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1wysac9++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:245
W20150714-18:56:53.775(-7)? (STDERR)                        throw(ex);
W20150714-18:56:53.775(-7)? (STDERR)                              ^
W20150714-18:56:53.778(-7)? (STDERR) TypeError: undefined is not a function
W20150714-18:56:53.778(-7)? (STDERR)     at app/collections/posts.js:1:44
W20150714-18:56:53.778(-7)? (STDERR)     at app/collections/posts.js:3:3
W20150714-18:56:53.778(-7)? (STDERR)     at /Users/TXC/code/microscope/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:222:10
W20150714-18:56:53.778(-7)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
W20150714-18:56:53.778(-7)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (/Users/TXC/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1wysac9++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
W20150714-18:56:53.778(-7)? (STDERR)     at /Users/TXC/code/microscope/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:117:5
=> Exited with code: 8
W20150714-18:56:55.400(-7)? (STDERR)          
W20150714-18:56:55.400(-7)? (STDERR) /Users/TXC/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1wysac9++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:245
W20150714-18:56:55.400(-7)? (STDERR)                        throw(ex);
W20150714-18:56:55.400(-7)? (STDERR)                              ^
W20150714-18:56:55.402(-7)? (STDERR) TypeError: undefined is not a function
W20150714-18:56:55.402(-7)? (STDERR)     at app/collections/posts.js:1:44
W20150714-18:56:55.402(-7)? (STDERR)     at app/collections/posts.js:3:3
W20150714-18:56:55.402(-7)? (STDERR)     at /Users/TXC/code/microscope/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:222:10
W20150714-18:56:55.403(-7)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
W20150714-18:56:55.403(-7)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (/Users/TXC/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1wysac9++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
W20150714-18:56:55.403(-7)? (STDERR)     at /Users/TXC/code/microscope/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:117:5
=> Exited with code: 8
=> Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change.
```

I don't really understand this error, and most importantly, I don't know where to look for to fix the problem.

Here are my JavaScript files:
 - posts_list.js

```
var postsData = [{
    title: 'Introducing Telescope',
    author: 'Sacha Greif',
    url: 'http://sachagreif.com/introducing-telescope/'
}, {
    title: 'Meteor',
    author: 'Tom Coleman',
    url: 'http://meteor.com/'
}, {
    title: 'The Meteor Book',
    author: 'Tom Coleman',
    url: 'http://themeteorbook.com/'
}];
if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Template.postsList.helpers({
        posts: postsData
    });
}
```

**post_item.js**

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Template.postItem.helpers({
        domain: function(){
            var a = document.createElement('a');
            a.href = this.url;
            return a.hostname;
        }
    });
}
```

**posts.js**

```
Posts = new Meteor.collection('posts');
```

And here are the html templates:

**posts_list.html**

```
<template name="postsLists">
    <div class="posts">
        {{#each posts}}
            {{> postItem}}
        {{/each}}
    </div>
</template>
```

**post_item.html**

```
<template name="postItem">
    <div class="post">
        <div class="post-content">
            <h3><a href="{{url}}">{{title}}</a><span>{{domain}}</span></h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Am I missing something obvious? Is this a version compatibility problem? Or is there a bug somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you misspell in `posts.js`: `Mongo.Collection`, it's capital `C`.