# Discover Meteor, Chapter 3-5: plain grey screen and no data

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteorite, meteor-blaze, meteor-helper

This is a follow-up question on [Meteor: "=> Exited with code: 8" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31420304/meteor-exited-with-code-8-error/31420471#31420471).

Since Chapter 3 of *[Discover Meteor](https://www.discovermeteor.com/)*, whenever I run the server and visit the `http://localhost:3000/` URL (or any other page of the app), I only get a plain, grey screen, with nothing on it:

[image]

I decided to go on with the tutorial, hoping that the next chapters would result in fixing what was wrong by updating some files, but it did not.

There is no error in the server log, so I cannot reproduce them here.

However, you can find all the files of the project on GitHub: https://github.com/thibaudclement/microscope

**UPDATE**: here are the client-side console logs:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Template.__create__ is not a function
meteor.js:225 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
iron-router.js:1475 Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
global-imports.js:3 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'RouteController' of undefined
template.layout.js:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: Template is not defined
template.loading.js:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: Template is not defined
template.post_item.js:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: Template is not defined
template.post_page.js:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: Template is not defined
template.posts_list.js:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: Template is not defined
template.main.js:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: Template is not defined
router.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: Router is not defined
post_item.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: Template is not defined
posts_list.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: Template is not defined
posts.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: Meteor is not defined
meteor.js:888 Exception in defer callback: TypeError: Cannot read property 'insert' of undefined
    at Utils.extend.autoRender (http://localhost:3000/packages/iron-router.js?af9f4791b8af4582a37d93bcade1eed163a976a8:1636:17)
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/iron-router.js?af9f4791b8af4582a37d93bcade1eed163a976a8:1465:16
    at _.extend.withValue (http://localhost:3000/packages/meteor.js?43b7958c1598803e94014f27f5f622b0bddc0aaf:955:17)
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/meteor.js?43b7958c1598803e94014f27f5f622b0bddc0aaf:435:45
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/packages/meteor.js?43b7958c1598803e94014f27f5f622b0bddc0aaf:983:22)
    at onGlobalMessage (http://localhost:3000/packages/meteor.js?43b7958c1598803e94014f27f5f622b0bddc0aaf:372:23)
```

Any idea of what I am doing wrong?

Or at least, where I should start looking to find what is going wrong?

Comment: what about client side console logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem may be you're following old version of the book or with microscope(not sure)

I cloned your app and tried to run

in your .meteor/packages file

change

```
iron-router
spin
```

to

```
 iron:router
 sacha:spin
```

it is working fine for me afer these changes

[image]